# TypeError: Cannot set property '' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

For some reason, I can't seem to bring this variable into scope to be manipulated.

Markup:

```
<label>Description only <input ng-model="filter.Description"></label><br>
<label>Tags only <input ng-model="filter.Tags.Text"></label><br> //This methodology works

<div ng-repeat="t in filteredTags" style="display:inline-block">
    <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="FilterByTag(t.Text)">
        {{t.Text}}
    </button>
</div> //But I want these buttons to work for the same thing, and they don't
```

.....

```
<tr ng-repeat="b in filteredBookmarks| filter: filter:strict">
```

JavaScript:

```
 $scope.FilterByTag = function (tagName) {
        filter.Tags.Text = tagName;
    };
```

If I change the JS variable to `$scope.filter.Tags.Text = tagName;`
I get an error that reads: `TypeError: Cannot set property 'Text' of undefined`.
Has anybody run into something similar?

Comment: You are not providing enough (or at least the relevant part of) code to understand what the issue is here. Obviously though, `filter.Tags` is undefined. Can you provide any code proving that `filter.Tags` exists? What is the `filter` object? Can you show us where you are creating it?

Comment: Also, shouldnt it be `$scope.filter.Tags...`?

Answer (score 2):

Try initializing your filter object first:

```
$scope.filter = {
    'Tags': {
        'Text': null
    },
    'Description': null
}
```

Comment: This was what I was missing, I tried doing this before, but with bad syntax, so you saved my bacon!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your function should read:

```
$scope.FilterByTag = function (tagName) {
    $scope.filter.Tags.Text = tagName;
};
```

Your `filter` object is on the `$scope`

Comment: This is also correct, and I had tried that but was getting an error from doing so.  @machinehead115 showed me what I was lacking to allow for that to work.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is because the hierarchy you are specifying for setting your tagName is not present. so it find the Tags itself is undefined and you are trying to set the Text value of it which is undefined and you got the error.

Try to specify a default data structure of your object where you want to store the value.

```
$scope.filter = {
  'Tags': {
      'Text': undefined
  },
  'Description': undefined
}
```